# How to skip the first key in an array in Jinja2?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have vars like this:

```
foo:
   - name: name-1
     var1_1: xxx
     var1_2: yyy
     var1_N: NNN
   - name: name-2
     var2_1: xxx
     var2_2: yyy
     var2_N: NNN
```

And need to get config file like this:

```
- name: 'name-1'
  configs:
  - var1_1: xxx
    var1_2: yyy
    var1_N: NNN
- name: 'name-2'
  configs:
  ....
```

I have loop in my jinja2 template:

```
{% for i in foo %}
- name: {{ i['name'] }}
  configs:
{% for key, value in i.items() %}
    - {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And in this loop i have 2 problems:

1 - how can i get just first line start with symbol "`-`" in second loop?

2 - how can i skip/brake "`name`" key in "`configs`" place? I need "name" just in `name: {{ i['name'] }}`.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this the wrong way IMO. In a nutshell:

```
{%- set result = [] -%}
{%- for i in foo -%}
{{- result.append({"name": i.name, "configs": [i | ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['name'])]}) -}}
{%- endfor -%}
{{ result | to_nice_yaml }}
```

The above solution requires installing the [`ansible.utils` collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/index.html). If you can't install it, you can achieve the same result with a bit more verbosity:

```
{%- set result = [] -%}
{%- for i in foo -%}
{%- set element = {"name": i.name} -%}
{%- set configs = {} -%}
{%- for k,v in i.items() -%}
{% if k != 'name' %}{{ configs.update({k:v}) }}{% endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
{{- element.update({"configs": [configs]}) -}}
{{- result.append(element) -}}
{%- endfor -%}
{{ result | to_nice_yaml }}
```